# php preg_replace charac. + numbers only + utf-8

Tags: php, preg-replace

I found this solution

```
$content=preg_replace('/[^\pL\p{Zs}]+/u', '', $string);
```

It removes everything except utf-8 characters, but I need except utf-8 characters and numbers is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding digits (\d) in range

```
$content=preg_replace('/[^\d\pL\p{Zs}]+/u', '', $string);
```